# Output the scale value for each data driven page (DDP)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, data-driven-pages

I'm using data driven pages (DDP) in ArcMap 10.3. The index layer is a polygon feature class and I would like to know the scale that each data driven page exports at. Ideally there would be a way to append an attribute to this layer that indicates the scale for each page (200+ pages). (I know DDP can be set on previously existing scale attribute value, but when its based on the various sizes of each polygon, I want to know what the numeric value is.

While that is my primary question, the ultimate goal is to be able to apply a different size label to corresponding features in each map. If I know the scale of each page, I can then adjust label size accordingly by page.

Comment: To do this I would use ["pseudo dynamic text"](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22pseudo+dynamic+text%22), which in essence is using ArcPy to update a text element at each page change.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix? I am working on a 623 page data driven map set and I to need to figure out a way to automatically populate a field with the scale that is generated when creating a the data driven map set, so I can then manipulate a few along the way to get my desired look.

Answer (score 2):

This method requires using python code to add the map scale values to each index feature which you may then hook to a Data Driven Page Attribute dynamic text:

1. Add index layer to map and create empty scale field in table
2. Use [da update cursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) to cursor through each feature
3. For each feature (within the nested for loop) use [Select Layer by Attribute](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-attribute.htm) method to select the current feature row
4. While feature is selected use the data frame zoom to selected feature method, `df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()`
5. Next, write the data frame scale property value, `df.scale`, to the selected feature scale field
6. Finally, once all feature have a scale value defined use the [Data Driven Page Attribute dynamic text](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/using-dynamic-text-with-data-driven-pages.htm) to reference the index layer scale field